# Memory location of function argument

Tags: c, memory, argument-passing

I'm preparing for my UNIX exam and there is a question about memory location of C variables.
Let's say we have code like this

```
char sth;
int some_function(int arg) {
   int some_int;
   // some code here
}
```

so I suppose that `sth` is located on the heap, `some_int` on the stack, but where is `arg` located?
Can somebody please explain how are C variables managed?

Thank you

Comment: Aren't they all on the stack?

Comment: Q: Aren't they all on the stack?  A: No.  "int some_int" is definitely on the stack.  "int arg" is definitely passed via the stack.  If it were a pointer, the pointer would be passed on the stack ... but the actual data being pointed to could be anywhere.  And "sth" appears to be static data, so it is *not* on the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that everything of this is implementation dependent. The C standard does not even utter the words stack, heap and so on. It just talks about the behavior that is expected from variables depending on their storage(`static`,`extern`,`register` etc).

Having said so usually `arg` will be located in the stack frame which is provided for the function. It's scope is limited to the function just as scope of `some_int`.

By the way `sth` is not on heap it has a static global storage.

Answer (score 1):

Everything here is totally platform dependent and really not about C the language, but about How My Compiler Does It.

`sth` has static (global) storage, so its probably not on the heap, but rather in the global data segment. `some_int` is indeed in the local stack frame of `some_function`. The variable `arg` is populated within `some_function`, but where it lives is up to the compiler and what's usually known as the "calling convention": It may be allocated and cleaned up in the stack frame of the caller or the callee, and by the caller or the callee, depending on conventions, or passed in a register and not go into memory at all.

Answer (score 0):

arg will be located in the stack (for desktop platforms at least).

Read a document called "smashing the stack for fun and profit" and you will understand how the memory is managed in C.

Answer (score 0):

`sth` is in the static memory, `arg` and `some_int` are in the stack. `arg` is copied ("pushed") to the stack when `some_function` is called. The heap is dynamic memory and contains data allocated at the run time (using `malloc` for example).

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are (with very few exceptions) passed on the stack.

You should be able to verify that they are in your computer architecture by just doing;

```
printf("%p - %p\n", &arg, &some_int);
```

They should normally be within a few bytes of each other.

Edit: As others have noted, sth is not allocated on the heap, but in the program's data segment, ie the compiler has already allocated the memory at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

sth is probably in [block static storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) (a.k.a. "BSS", depending on platform):

Again, this is entirely "platform dependent", but there are generally four regions "segments" where you can allocate variable space from:

a) Heap: your language's runtime manages "heap" data, e.g. with calls to "malloc()" or "new")

b) Stack: these are "automatic" variables

c) BSS: unintialized (variable) static data

d) Data: initialized (and often read-only) static data

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation; arguments may be pushed onto the stack frame, or they may be written to registers, or they may be passed by some other mechanism.

The language definition does not mandate where various objects  should be stored; it only mandates how those objects should behave.